# javascript or operation returns unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript. I have a programm like:

```
var a = 2

if(a !=2 || a != 3){
  console.log("not")
}
```

Here I have set the variable `a` value to `2`.

In my condition I have set `if a is not 2 or a is not 3` it should print `not`
But here `a's` value being `2` it is printing `not`.
It always give `not` whatever the value is

I can check this is python easily like:

`if not a == 2 or not a== 3`

Whats wrong in here ??

Comment: One problem is that your python code is actually the same. What you might mean in the python example is this: `not ( a == 2 or a == 3 )`, which has the js equivalent `!(a==2||a==3)`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var a = 2
> ```

`a` is now `2`.

> ```
> a !=2
> ```

This is `false`, so we look on the other side of the or

> ```
> a != 3
> ```

This is true. So one of the two sides of the or test is true. Therefore the or test is true.

---

If you want to test if a value is not 2 **and** it is **also** not 3, then you need to use an `&&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
if(a !=2 && a != 3){
  console.log("not")
}
```

In other words, if a is not 2 AND a is not 3.
This is just how boolean logic works. In your example, because a does not equal 3, the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation

```
false || true = true

a != 2 //returns false
a != 3 //returns true
```

In python:

```
not a == 2 // returns false
not a == 3 //returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [how logical operators work](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Your condition evaluates to true if *a is not 2* or *a is not 3*, that means that is will be false only when **a is both 2 and 3 at the same time** which isn't possible - this condition will always be true.

You might be also interested in reading something on [mathematical logic and negations](http://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/3_logic/we_3_negation.html).

If you want to ensure that *a is not 2 or 3* then you should change it to

```
if((a != 2) && (a != 3)){
```

as in *a is not 2 and a is not 3* - keep in mind that you are working with 2 statements.

Answer (score 0):

"OR" in the condition means that the statement in the if block will get executed if any one of the equations out of

```
(a != 2)
```

and

```
(a != 3)
```

returns true.

In your code snippet

```
(a != 3)
```

is true and hence the statement

```
console.log("not");
```

gets executed.

Answer (score -1):

This is very expected behaviour and it work same in python and javascript

```
a = 2
if not a == 2 or not a== 3:
    print ("not")
```

is equivalent to

```
var a = 2

if(a !=2 || a != 3){
  console.log("not")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in **or** expression conditions check while one of theme be come true or until there was no condition.